# Set Webview2 Source directly to a binary stream

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, winforms, webview2

I have a Webview2 Control in my application, used to view PDF documents.
The application also stores to and reads from MS SQL server PDFs data.

Currently, I am retrieving binary data from SQL, convert them to a temporary file to disk and set:

```
webview2.source = New Uri("file://" + filename)
```

That's working fine so far, but of course I would like to do the job without writing and reading to and from disk.

Is there a way to do the same without accessing the disk?

Update (as recommended), what I tried. With part of code for better understandg:

```
                Dim fieldOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal(ColumnName)
                reader.Read()
                Dim blob = New Byte(reader.GetBytes(fieldOrdinal, 0, Nothing, 0, 0) - 1) {}
                reader.GetBytes(fieldOrdinal, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length)

                Dim pdfBase64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(blob)
                Dim html As String = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div>" & $"<iframe width=100% height=500 src=\" & Chr(&H22) & "data:Application/pdf;base64,{pdfBase64}\" & Chr(&H22) & ">" & "</iframe></div></body></html>"
```

The `webview2` control shows a frame, but without content

Final Update:
Here the (correct) to VB translated and working code:

```
Dim html As String = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div>" & $"<iframe width=100% height=500 src=""data:Application/pdf;base64,{pdfBase64}"">" & "</iframe></div></body></html>"
```

Comment: The value in `src` needs to be surrounded in quotes. Also  the  backslash was an escape for `"` in C#.

Comment: Got it ! The equivalent in VB is "".
Working ! Thx to both of you !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can embed the PDF in an `IFRAME` as Base64, the same way you embed images.
In this case, the mime type is of course `application/pdf`.
Convert to Base64 your source PDF bytes with [Convert.ToBase64String()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string), use a standard HTML5 header and set the `IFRAME` and/or `DIV` container to the desired size.

Use the [WebView2.NavigateToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.navigatetostring) method to load the HTML with the embedded PDF:

- See the Remarks section: currently the content's size cannot exceed `2097152` bytes (2MB)

```
string pdfBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String([Your PDF bytes]);

string html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div>" +
    $"<iframe width=100% height=500 src=\"data:application/pdf;base64,{pdfBase64}\">" +
    "</iframe></div></body></html>";

webView2.NavigateToString(html);
```

VB.Net version:

```
Dim pdfBytes = [DataReader].GetSqlBytes([DataReader].GetOrdinal("[Column Name]")).Value
Dim pdfBase64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(pdfBytes)

Dim html As String = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div>" &
    $"<iframe width=100% height=500 src=""data:Application/pdf;base64,{pdfBase64}"">" &
    "</iframe></div></body></html>"

webView2.NavigateToString(html)
```

---

The `iframe` size should not be set like that, you should use CSS styles (and probably a simple JavaScript to handle *late* redefinition of the size of the Window that contains your PDF).
You could build a simple HTML template and fill the Base64 content as described.

Answer (score 1):

Just to finalize the answer. Below the final version I'm using, including CSS in the framing HTML to make the pdf borderless and 100% x 100% size of the parent `webview2`:

```
Dim pdfBase64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(pdfBytes)
Dim html As String = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
                            </head>
                            <style>
                                   body   {margin: 0;}
                                   iframe {display: block; background: #000; border: none; height: 100vh; width: 100vw;}
                            </style>
                            <body>" & $"<iframe src=""data:Application/pdf;base64,{pdfBase64}"">" & "</iframe></body></html>"
```