# Embed resource image inside HTML on WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, vb.net, image, resources, webbrowser-control

I am populating resource images into an HTML table on a WebBrowser control.  Thus far, I can convert images to Byte using the function listed below, but am unable to cast the memory stream into the HTML:

Dim imgBase64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(BmpToBytes_MemStream(My.Resources.myimage))

```
Dim str1 as String = ""

str1 += ("<table class=" & """" & "mycssclass" & """" & " Align=center>")
str1 += ("<caption><b>My Caption</b></caption>")
str1 += "<tr><td><iframe width=100% height=100% src=imgBase64></iframe></td></tr>"
str1 += ("</table>")
WebBrowser1.Refresh()
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = str1
```

Below is the image BMP to byte function:

```
 Private Function BmpToBytes_MemStream(ByVal bmp As Bitmap) As Byte()
        Return new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(bmp, GetType(byte()))
 End Function
```

There is an example of loading a pdf into an IFRAME inside the HTML, like this:

```
  $"<iframe width=100% height=500 src=""data:Application/pdf;base64,{pdfBase64}"">"
```

However, I am unsure of the exact syntax required for displaying the Base64 image inside the IFRAME in HTML. Also, is the "$" character needed?

Comment: You can use a Base64 string as described in: [Set Webview2 Source directly to a binary stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68671066/7444103). As also described there, use a HTML5 header. In this case, you may want to add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to `<HEAD>` -- Not sure how CSS is related to this.

Comment: See modified OP.  The answer you referenced is helpful strictly for embedding a PDF inside an IFRAME environment within HTML, but is noninformative regarding embedding an image into an IFRAME in HTML.  Especially the syntax: `data:Application/pdf`.

Comment: Well, you just need the Base64 conversion functionality, that's the important part. The `SRC` Attribute of an `<IMG>` element can be set directly the same way. -- Of course you don't use `Application/pdf` as mime type, you can use `image/png` or `image/jpeg` etc. Set this value too, based on the type of the Image you're dealing with (as everyone else does). You can also convert all incoming images to a single format, e.g., PNG (default Format), so you don't have to bother.

Comment: BTW, this is very wrong: `Dim bmpBytes() As Byte = ms.GetBuffer()`. You need `ms.ToArray()`. But, use the ImageConverter class instead: e.g., just `return new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(bmp, GetType(byte()))`. You can convert back from a byte array with `dim imageFromBytes = DirectCast(New ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(imageBytes), Image)`

Comment: Removed size requirements, and this is what is in the HMTL source at run-time: so it looks okay?  `<iframe src="image/png;base64,{imgBase64}"></iframe>`

Comment: It's what you have posted above, changing the mime type: `$"<iframe src=""data:image/png;base64,{pngBase64}"">"`, where `pngBase64` is the Base64 of the Image bytes. -- As mentioned, you don't need an IFrame, you can set `$"<img src = ""data:image/png;base64,{pdfBase64}"">"` directly. The `width` and `height` attributes you can get them from the Bitmap and set those values, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jimi's comments, I wanted to condense the discussion to an answer that worked.

Add the following function somewhere in your code:

```
Private Function BmpToBytes_MemStream(ByVal bmp As Bitmap) As Byte()
    Return New ImageConverter().ConvertTo(bmp, GetType(Byte()))
End Function
```

Next, convert the resource image (which is a png image named myimage.png) to Base64:

```
 Dim myimage64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(BmpToBytes_MemStream(My.Resources.myimage))
```

Finally, embed the converted image in HTML code using e.g.:

```
Dim str1 as String = ""

str1 += "<table class=" & """" & "mycssclass" & """" & " Align=center>"
str1 += "<caption><b>My Caption</b></caption>"
str1 += "<tr><td>$"<img src = ""data:image/png;base64,{myimage64}"">"</td></tr>"
str1 += ("</table>")
WebBrowser1.Refresh()
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = str1
```

Comment: If you need the Mime-Type, you can get it with `dim mimeType = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(Function(enc) enc.FormatID = bmp.RawFormat.Guid)?.MimeType`